# Select only those records that have same multiple values for a particular column if it's existing?

Tags: postgresql, group-by, distinct, exists, case-sensitive

Below is an example of my pricing_supports table have more than 3 milions rows. 
There some rows having same values in the first_origin_id, delivery_id fields. 
If there're records with same first_origin_id, delivery_id but different source, I only want to select those records source = 0

```
ID   code first_origin_id    delivery_id    source
1      A       10                20              0
2      B       10                20              1
3      C       11                21              1
4      D       12                22              0
5      E       12                22              1
```

I would like result like that:

```
ID   code first_origin_id    delivery_id    source
1      A       10                20              0
3      C       11                21              1
4      D       12                22              0
```

How can i do for good performace?

Answer (score 0):

By using [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/) and `PARTITION BY first_origin_id, delivery_id` then `ORDER BY source`, you can achieve your expected result.

So the query will be:

```
SELECT ID, code, first_origin_id, delivery_id, source FROM (
  SELECT ID, code, first_origin_id, delivery_id, source, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY first_origin_id, delivery_id ORDER BY source, ID) AS RowNumber
  FROM pricing_supports
) Q
WHERE Q.RowNumber = 1
```

Please find the <kbd>[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0a91152379c86f556879e9381fbc71e6)</kbd>

Comment: It's work, but not best way for performance. I think.  thanks @Arulkumar